# Invalid Syntax on .findall (text) highlighting just the ( or random letter?

Tags: python

When attempting to run this I get an 'Invalid Syntax' error and it will highlight either the ( 't' or the space in line

extractedPhone = phoneRegex.findall (text)

Any reasons why? Double checked all other () to ensure everything was opened and closed, renamed text to sample, not sure what is going on!

The goal of this is to search for phone numbers and emails from PDF just by copying the file and then running this.

Thank you

```
#! Python3

import re
import pyperclip

#create a regex for phone numbers

phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''

((\d\d\d)|(\(\d\d\d\)))?    #area code optional
(\s | -)                    #first seperator
\d\d\d                      #three digits
(\s | -)                    #second seperator
\d\d\d\d                    #last four digits
(((ext(\.)?\s)|x)           #ext. 12345
(\d{2,5))?                  #ext optional number

''', re.VERBOSE)

#create a regex for email addresses

emailRegex = re.compile('''(
[A-Za-z0-9-_+.]+            #name part (AZaz+_-.)
@                           #@
[A-Za-z0-9-_+.]+            #domain
)''' re.VERBOSE)

#get text off the clipboard
text = pyperclip.paste()


#extract the email / phone from this text
extractedPhone = phoneRegex.findall (text) #here is the issue line
extractedEmail = emailRegex.findall (text)

allPhoneNumber = []
for numbers in extractedPhone:
    allPhoneNumbers.append(phoneNumber[0])

print (extractedPhone)
print (extractedEmail)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On this line here,

```
emailRegex = re.compile('''(
[A-Za-z0-9-_+.]+            #name part (AZaz+_-.)
@                           #@
[A-Za-z0-9-_+.]+            #domain
)''', re.VERBOSE) # you missed a comma here after triple-quote.
```

Comment: Please don't answer a question if the only correction is to fix a typo.